# Зачем нужны ключи в пакетных менеджерах Linux?

Tags: linux, gpg, пакетный-менеждер

Как известно, пакетные менеджеры в `Linux` используют ключи `.gpg`.
В чём их смысл и как это работает?

Comment: Чтобы посторонний злоумышленник не мог подсунуть вредоносный пакет вместо настоящего. А как работает — почитайте любую статью в интернете про криптографические подписи

Comment: @andreymal после вашего комментария стало понятнее. Но вот непонятно осталось, каким образом злоумышленник может подменить пакет. Где-нибудь бы подробнее об этом почитать.

Comment: Ну это уже как повезёт: может, подменит http-трафик (если он контролирует подключение к интернету), а может, взломает сам репозиторий и закачает туда вредоносный пакет. Но если он не получит доступ к закрытому ключу разработчика для создания криптографической подписи, то вредоносный пакет не пройдёт проверку и будет отклонён

Comment: @andreymal ну то есть единственный вариант для него распространить пакет хоть для кого-то - это подменить открытый ключ на ресурсе, на котором разработчик его распространяет, чтобы хотя бы новые пользователи скачали его пакет?

Comment: Возможно, но это сама по себе непростая задача. (Ну или можно тупо украсть закрытый ключ у разработчика, и тогда подпись уже не поможет, потому что злоумышленник сможет сделать её)